# STM32 for audio processing

Tags: analog, audio, stm32, signal-processing

I'm working on a project. I do not know which microcontroller to use for real-time audio processing, and I want to recognize the peak with it.

I have already implemented this program with Raspberry Pi.

Can do this STM32F103 or another microcontroller?

Comment: You don't even say which of the different STM32F103 models, as they come in multiple sizes, either quite small with limited set of peripherals, or very large with extensive set of peripherals. Which audio interface you would be using? How much processing you are doing, what is the sampling rate, bit depth, number of channels, and what processing will be done? What will be the audio output?

Comment: Sample rate 44,100 and Mono

Comment: Make sure that whichever STM32 you use has a floating point unit and ideally DSP exrensions

Comment: @Robin - Are you the OP (Jason) with a different account? I only ask as your late [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/346674) seems to deviate drastically from the original post.

Comment: @Robin - Hi, The approval of your suggested edit has been reversed, as explained in the previous comment. Even if you are the same person as the OP, it's too late to make such a significant change to the original question. Also you were asking for a product recommendation which is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here. || If you have an on-topic question of your own, please ask it as a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Finding a peak is very simple; you just need to iterate through all samples, and check whether the current sample is higher than the highest you saw so far. If yes, you store its index (if you care about the index) or its value in a variable.

After you've done that, you just use that variable.

Now, this feels like something a >48 MHz clocked ARM could easily do. The question is whether *you* can write enough C to implement that - but it's really not a very hard task.

The hard part is getting the audio into your microcontroller, and doing something with the peak. Quite likely you'll also want to pre-process the audio (Square it and low-pass filter that?).

So, that's where your microcontroller might or might not reach its limits. From your description alone, finding a maximum of samples coming through at an audio-typical sampling rate, this should be fine. But it's really not the hard part.

Comment: I tried with Arduino UNO R3 but I do not have a negative peak 
https://www.uplooder.net/img/image/81/bddfe6148e64199f5e457e51e9eec4ac/Capture.PNG

Comment: I can't debug your code for you; this is not a problem of your microcontroller being able to, this is a problem of your code.